# How to control image previews for links to readthedocs/ sphinx page?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

Is there a setting I can tweak in `conf.py` to ensure that image previews are generated for links to my index.html?

I think I need to put a link to the image inside:

```
<head><meta name="og:image" content="https://.png" /></head>
```

Maybe a setting on one of the `html_*` options? I read through them, but did not see anything.

> https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html

[image]

Page to link to: https://aiqc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: This is totally dependent on your chosen Sphinx theme. Please check its documentation to see if this feature is supported. AFAIK, Sphinx out of the box has no such feature. You might be able to [modify a theme](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython-sphinx%5D+customize+theme) to support image link previews.

Comment: https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme/issues/1042

Comment: The RTD theme does not support this feature. You must customize the RTD theme, or submit a pull request that adds this feature. Welcome to open source software, where non-existent features are created by the people who actually use them.

Comment: @StevePiercy looks like i live another day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of many meta tags available in:

> https://github.com/wpilibsuite/sphinxext-opengraph

**conf.py**

```py
extensions = ['sphinxext.opengraph']

ogp_image = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aiqc/aiqc/main/docs/images/aiqc_logo_banner_controlroom.png"
```

It even has a field for user-defined `<meta>` tags.